# SQL trigger that changes the wrong date

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, triggers

how can I make an SQL trigger in Oracle, which will check day and month of date inserted and if it's not Jan 1st, the trigger updates it?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Contract (
Ends_on DATE NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO Contract (Ends_on)
VALUES (TO_DATE('2017-1-30','yyyy-mm-dd'));
```

in this case, the date should automatically change to '2017-1-1'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's your trigger code so far, and what *exact* problem do you have?

Comment: Why not just store the year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger would look like this, making use of the `TRUNC` function with second argument `'YEAR'`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_ins_contract
    BEFORE INSERT ON Contract 
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :new.Ends_on := TRUNC(:new.Ends_on, 'YEAR');
END;
/
```